# MySQL equals this||that

Tags: mysql

Before I get blasted note that I have Google searched for this but defining the search term is as tricky as solving the problem.

I have a SELECT statement with the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE type = 1||3
```

Does not work it actually returns all variations of type (1:6).

Then tried:

```
WHERE type = (1||3)
```

But that just returned where type = 1 and excluded where type equals 3.

How do I tell SQL to return records where type equals either 1 or 3 in this way?

P.S. I know I can do this: `WHERE type IN (1,3)`

But I just want to know how to do it using the double bar operator?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to rewrite the whole `type=?` condition like this:

```
WHERE type = 1 OR type = 3
WHERE type = 1 || type = 3
```

If you want to say `WHERE` `type` is `1` or `3`, that is a perfect use for `IN` (read it out loud):

```
WHERE type IN (1, 3)
```

Comment: In other words, use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).